# aws ec2 connection between 2 diffrent vpc

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have two machines in different accounts.
I'm trying to make a connection between them.
So I added a rule that allows all traffic from the external and internal one.

Outbound allows all traffic for both machines but there's no connection at all.

one machine : 172.31.43.115
second machine : 172.31.26.95

I pinged. No response.
I also tried Trace route, but also no response

I searched for a guide on Google, but had no luck.
I understand that I have to do Route.

How can I do that? Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like (based off the IPs) you are mistaking the *private* IP with the *public* IP.  Check your EC2 console again, and click on the instance and look at the bottom metadata.  On the right column nearish to the top there should be public IP.

Comment: account aa@account1.com with vps . Private IPs
172.31.43.115 and account number 2 bbb@dasddas.com with vps. Private IPs
172.31.26.9

Comment: What I'm saying is that you need to connect with the *public* IP.  Not private.

Comment: i try it , if i doing "wget" from public ip for exmple: 1.1.1.1 from 2.2.2.2 i get the error " wget 2.2.2.2
--2015-03-25 10:25:28--  http://2.2.2.2/
Connecting to 2.2.2.2:80... failed: No route to host.
"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate them externally, you should attache an EIP ( elastic ip ) to them and allow in Security group. If you need to communicate internally , you should create vpc peering.